# Mongo db gets truncated frequently

Tags: python, django, database, mongodb, pymongo

Django version 3.0.5
mongo version 4.4.6

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': True,
        'NAME': 'cpv',
        'HOST': 'xx.xx.xx.xxx',
        'PORT': 27017,
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE': "admin"
    }
}
```

When I enable authorization in mongod.conf

```
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

And try to migrate I am getting below error

pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command listCollections requires authentication, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'command listCollections requires authentication', 'code': 13, 'codeName': 'Unauthorized'}

Answer (score 0):

I've downgraded the version of djongo from 1.3.3 to 1.2.38

```
djongo==1.2.38
```

Now I am able to apply authorization on mongodb